# Spring Boot application.yml double backslash interpreted literally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm on Spring Boot 1.5.8

My `application.yml` has a following property:

```
my:
  path: \\\\hostname\\dir
```

From what I understand from the [YAML spec *5.7. Escaped Characters*](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092) a double backslash `\\` is a valid escape sequence for a single backslash, so the above configuration should yield a value of `my.path: \\hostname\dir`.

However, in my application I can see that the value of the property contains doubled backslashes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PropTest {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class MyProp {
        private String path;
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyProp my;

    @Test
    public void testProp() {
        System.out.println(my.path);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("my")
        public MyProp my() {
            return new MyProp();
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
\\\\host\\dir
```

I cannot put the value in `application.yml` in quotes, because the file is generated by a provisioning system (SaltStack) and it has its own Yaml rendering library.

Is it a bug in Spring Boot / a Yaml library used by Spring Boot? Is there a way to force Spring Boot to treat double backslash in Yaml as an escape of a single backslash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the spec section you linked:

> Note that escape sequences are only interpreted in double-quoted scalars. In all other scalar styles, the “\” character has no special meaning and non-printable characters are not available.

So if you do not double-quote the scalar, `\` is a normal character like any other and you can just write

```
my:
  path: \\hostname\dir
```

Comment: It seems in that case that SaltStack is rendering the file incorrectly (it should either put the value in quotes or not duplicate the slashes). Thanks for pushing me in the right direction, that's very helpful.